# How to translate this CSS to webkit

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, jquery-mobile, safari

I have the following CSS:

```
 background: linear-gradient(0deg,  transparent 0px, transparent 1px, #f0f0f0 1px, #f0f0f0 100%);
```

Now I'd like to make it work for: Safari 4 and Safari 5.1+

What is the syntax for making `-webkit-linear-graient`  and  `-webkit-gradient`.

here it is: when open in safari, doesn't show same as in Chrome or Firefox

http://jsfiddle.net/df9z9/

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg,  transparent 0px, transparent 1px, #f0f0f0 1px, #f0f0f0 100%);
background: linear-gradient(0deg,  transparent 0px, transparent 1px, #f0f0f0 1px, #f0f0f0 100%);
```

Comment: it is not working. http://jsfiddle.net/df9z9/3/, you see, when you open it in safari...it shows different

Comment: Be careful with the angle ! From Mozilla developper:  Following the initial Apple proposal, the prefixed variants of the syntax all uses the an <angle> defined like polar angles, that is with 0deg representing the East. To be coherent with the rest of CSS, the specification defines an angle with 0deg representing the North.

Answer (score 1):

Use this gradient generator it will help it be cross browser supportive:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

You can even import from previous css I imported your gradient and this is what it gave

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(240,240,240,1) 1px); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1px,rgba(240,240,240,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(240,240,240,1) 1px); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(240,240,240,1) 1px); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(240,240,240,1) 1px); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(240,240,240,1) 1px); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f0f0f0', endColorstr='#f0f0f0',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

That code may not be what your looking for, but you can try the gradient generator and put in your own stops and everything.